Improve performance of PostgreSQL query function
I have a server (pysical server, AMD Ryzen 7 PRO 8700GE (5.1Ghz)) , 64gbram, raid0 nvme) here which runs a PostgreSQL/PostGIS server serving around 60.000.000 datapoints of data like this:
id::text
metadataid::text
location::geometry (point)
groundgeometry::geometry (multipolygon)
feature::jsonb (can be up to ~500kb)

There are gix indices for bbox, groundgeometry, location and also an index for id.
Then there is another table with around 50.000 lines like this:
id::string
metadataid::string
translate::real[]
scale::real[]
epsg::string
state::string
bbox::geometry (polygons)
created_at::timestamp
changed_at::timestamp
filename::string

There is an index for filename and metadataid
To do that I have a db function like this:
DECLARE
  cityjson_text bytea;
BEGIN
  SELECT INTO cityjson_text json_agg(cityjson) FROM (
    SELECT
      json_build_object(
        'tileboundary', ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_TileEnvelope(z, x, y, margin => 0.015625))::json,
        'groundgeometry', ST_AsGeoJSON(groundgeometry)::json,
        'location', ST_AsGeoJSON(location)::json,
        'bbox', ST_AsGeoJSON(g.bbox)::json,
        'cityJson', 
        CASE WHEN z > 14 THEN json_build_object( 'cityjsonFeature',cityjsonfeature,
                              'cityJsonMetadata',json_build_object( 'translate',m.translate::float[],
                                                                   'scale',m.scale,
                                                                   'epsg', m.epsg)
                            )
        ELSE null END
      ) AS cityjson
    FROM 
      cj_geometry g
    LEFT JOIN metadata m ON g.metadataid = m.metadataid
    WHERE 
      groundgeometry && ST_TileEnvelope(z, x, y, margin => 0.015625)
    AND 
    -- only intesect if there is a geojson exclude present
      (geojson_input IS NULL OR NOT ST_Intersects(groundgeometry, ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geojson_input), 3857)))
  ) AS cityjson_query;
      -- RAISE NOTICE 'Resulting cityjson_text: %', geojson_input;

  RETURN cityjson_text;
END;



The database is using PostGIS 3.0 with the following settings:
max_connections = 40
shared_buffers = 16GB
effective_cache_size = 48GB
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 500
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200
work_mem = 26214kB
huge_pages = try
min_wal_size = 4GB
max_wal_size = 16GB
max_worker_processes = 16
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 8
max_parallel_workers = 16
max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 4

What I am wondering now is how to make the queries faster.
The first issue I am having is, that it seems to always only use one core for a query process. Isn't the max_parallel_workers_per_gather supposed to change that?

How would I need to change the function to make it work somewhat in parallel?
What else could be changed to make it work more performant?
What query times would I need to accept on this kind of setup?

EDIT: some EXPLAIN ANALYZE outputs:
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE) 
SELECT * FROM cj_geometry 
WHERE groundgeometry && ST_TileEnvelope(17,70414,42986, margin => 0.015625);


"Index Scan using city_object_groundgeometry_gix on public.cj_geometry  (cost=0.42..50.69 rows=44 width=1241) (actual time=0.120..0.155 rows=5 loops=1)"
"  Output: id, metadataid, location, groundgeometry, bbox, cityjsonfeature"
"  Index Cond: (cj_geometry.groundgeometry && '0103000020110F00000100000005000000E00EC284EAC1364128DF415BB94C5A41E00EC284EAC13641C8FDA12E084D5A41608942D225C33641C8FDA12E084D5A41608942D225C3364128DF415BB94C5A41E00EC284EAC1364128DF415BB94C5A41'::geometry)"
"Planning Time: 1.628 ms"
"Execution Time: 0.181 ms"

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE) 
select _a_get_cityjson(17,70400,42086)


"Result  (cost=0.00..0.26 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=11.613..11.614 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Output: _a_get_cityjson(17, 70400, 42086, NULL::text)"
"Planning Time: 0.035 ms"
"Execution Time: 11.638 ms"


What is the query supposed to do?

please also add the explain output for the query

@IanTurton i have edited the original post

it doesn't look like it takes long enough to be worth parallelising, though I don't know how the Postgis query planner decides that

RE: parallel query: the only feasible leverage point for query plan distribution would be the Index scan - which is rightfully chosen as JOIN strategy over a sequential scan of that large table - and a parallel index scan is currently only supported for btree indexes. Apart from that, I doubt that the planner would ever chose a parallel plan whatsoever, considering the filter condition and estimated result row count, as well as the approximate index block size of the joined table (firing up and managing threads is costly and the index block count to be distributed should be high enough)

That being said, obviously most time will be spent transforming, serializing and aggregating the column values into JSON - both the geometries inside (in particular), as well as the wrapping object; consider using pre-serialized column values if this is time critical. Then I am seeing repeated calls to ST_TileEnvelope, why not making that a function variable and calculate only once? But also, if all you do is SELECT, why writing a plpgsql function? Please also add the EXPLAIN plan for the actual query run inside the function.
